# What does "+=" operator do?

Tags: java, operators

I've seen code example that had

```
x += y
```

and I can't seem to find any explanation for this.

Please help.  Thanks.

Comment: You really couldn't google search "plus equals operator"?

Comment: It simply is the shorthand form of x=x+y.   Although I am quite surprised you did not find anything on this

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an extremely basic question that provides little value to other users. A brief read of introductory Java documentation would answer this question.

Comment: @AnkurJain I strongly recommend you read the accepted answer of the duplicate question.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem thanks for correcting me. That was some new information for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html

> You can also combine the arithmetic operators with the simple assignment operator to create compound assignments. For example, x+=1; and x=x+1; both increment the value of x by 1.

Comment: Why the -1? you may dislike the question, but I thought this answer helped?

Comment: I up-voted, but your not technically supposed to answer duplicates, poorly written questions, or any questions that show no research effort. This question seems like all 3 of these things combined.

Comment: Do you have a source for that? It's news to me.

Comment: Also I saw a new Stack Overflow user that was looking for guidance, figured giving them an answer, as well as letting them know the etiquette seems a lot less abrasive then giving them no answers and having their question flagged / deleted. This community gets an awful bad rep sometimes with the way it deals with new users.

Comment: Yes, I do have a source. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Near the bottom it says _"Answer [well asked](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions"_ look at the third bullet point.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to improve.